# Find $ y''$ and $ y'''$ if $b^2x^2+a^2y^2=a^2b^2$

Tags: calculus, differential

answers :- $$y''=-\frac{b^4}{a^2y^3}$$ and  $$ y'''=-\frac{3b^6x}{a^4y^5}$$i have tried solve in this manner:-$$b^2x^2+a^2y^2=a^2b^2  -1.)$$
diff wrt x :$$2b^2x+2a^2y'=0$$
 $$a^2y'=-b^2x$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-b^2x}{a^2y}$$
on substituting eq -1 we get :-
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-b^2x}{a \sqrt{a^2b^2-b^2x^2}}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-a^{-1}.b^2.x.(a^2b^2-b^2x^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$$on diff wrtx :- 
$$y''=\frac{-b}{a}[(a^2b^2-b^2x^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}+{-\frac{1}{2}}(a^2b^2-b^2x^2)^{-\frac{3}{2}}.-2b^2.x.x]$$
$$y''=\frac{-b}{a}[(a^2b^2-b^2x^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}+(a^2b^2-b^2x^2)^{-\frac{3}{2}}.b^2.x^2]$$
now substituting$(a^2b^2-b^2x^2)$as $a^2y^2$ from eq -1.):-
 $$y''=b^2\frac{(a^2y^2)^3+ax^2}{a(a^2y^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$**This was all i could have done someone please help**

Comment: You need to define what are $y_i, i=1,2,3$.

Comment: 1,2... are number of times i have differenciated

Comment: It is better to use $y^{(i)}$ to represent such quantities.

Comment: ok. i will represent them as you have told me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not very clear but it seems that you are writing $y_1$ for the derivative of $y$ and $y_2$ for the second derivative.

If I am correct in this, then
$$\eqalign{b^2x^2+a^2y^2=a^2b^2\quad
  &\Rightarrow\quad 2b^2x+2a^2yy'=0\cr
  &\Rightarrow\quad 2b^2+2a^2(yy''+(y')^2)=0\qquad(*)\cr
  &\Rightarrow\quad y''=-\frac{b^2}{a^2y}-\frac{(a^2yy')^2}{a^4y^3}\cr
  &\Rightarrow\quad y''=-\frac{a^2b^2y^2+b^4x^2}{a^4y^3}\cr
  &\Rightarrow\quad y''=-\frac{b^2(a^2b^2)}{a^4y^3}=-\frac{b^4}{a^2y^3}\ .\cr}$$
You can use similar ideas to find $y'''$: it will probably be easiest to begin by differentiating $(*)$.

Comment: No problem!  Note that in your answer, the first differentiation is wrong - though you have corrected the mistake 2 lines later, it was probably just a typing slip.

Comment: y did'nt i get same answer as you.in the second differention??

Comment: In the first step of your second differentiation you have a $b$ when it should be $b^2$.  Apart from that it looks correct but I cannot see what you have done in the final step - I think the $(a^2y^2)^3$ should just be $a^2y^2$, and the $b^2x$ has turned into $ax$.  Not quite sure.